# How to count down after reaching max

Tags: math, angle, degrees

I'm working with degrees and I need a separate value to stay within a specific range.

The degrees I'm working with are from 0 to 180 and I need the separate variable to interpret it as:

**- 0.0f degrees = 0.0f**

**- 90.0f degrees = 1.0f**

**- 180.0f degrees = 0.0f**

Currently, I have this that goes from 0.0f to 1.0f for degrees 0.0f to 90.0f:

```
float unit = 1.0f / 90.0f; // equivalent of 1 degree
value = unit * maths::toDegrees(angle);
```

What I'm trying to figure out is to have `value count down back to 0 the closer it gets 180 degrees.

Comment: Why would you not just add a bool or ternary to determine addition or subtraction. value = degrees >= 90.0 ? value - yourincrement : value + yourincrement;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute value of difference with 90:

value = 1.0 - unit * math::**Abs**(90 - maths::toDegrees(angle));

P.S. If you want smooth dependence, consider

value = maths::**Sin**(angle);

It is equal to zero in 0, reaches max value 1 at Pi/2=90, and diminishes to zero at Pi=180